# How Can we get the lifecycle of StatefulWidget in flutter? I want to determine the lifecycle of widget on current screen not of complete app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

How Can we get the lifecycle of StatefulWidget in flutter, if should pause if user is navigating to differnt screen and resume if user comes back to the screen.

didChangeAppLifecycleState giving lifecycle of app, not of the particular screen widget

Answer (score 0):

Try [FocusDetector](https://pub.dev/packages/focus_detector), which is the closest to `viewWillAppear/Disappear` methods as seen on iOS.

```
FocusDetector(
      onFocusLost: () {
        logger.i(
          'Focus Lost.'
          '\nTriggered when either [onVisibilityLost] or [onForegroundLost] '
          'is called.'
          '\nEquivalent to onPause() on Android or viewDidDisappear() on iOS.',
        );
      },
      onFocusGained: () {
        logger.i(
          'Focus Gained.'
          '\nTriggered when either [onVisibilityGained] or [onForegroundGained] '
          'is called.'
          '\nEquivalent to onResume() on Android or viewDidAppear() on iOS.',
        );
      },
      onVisibilityLost: () {
        logger.i(
          'Visibility Lost.'
          '\nIt means the widget is no longer visible within your app.',
        );
      },
      onVisibilityGained: () {
        logger.i(
          'Visibility Gained.'
          '\nIt means the widget is now visible within your app.',
        );
      },
      onForegroundLost: () {
        logger.i(
          'Foreground Lost.'
          '\nIt means, for example, that the user sent your app to the background by opening '
          'another app or turned off the device\'s screen while your '
          'widget was visible.',
        );
      },
      onForegroundGained: () {
        logger.i(
          'Foreground Gained.'
          '\nIt means, for example, that the user switched back to your app or turned the '
          'device\'s screen back on while your widget was visible.',
        );
      },
      child: Container(),
    );
```